# multi column grouping and totaling in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, group-by

my data looks like this

```
 ___________________________________
|name  date      status    location |
|Tom   1/1/2010  Ready     Home     |
|Tom   1/1/2010  Ready     Home     |
|Bill  1/18/2010 Go        Work     |
|Bob   2/19/2010 Ready     Field    |
|Bob   2/19/2010 Ready     Field    |
|Wil   4/5/2010  Steady    Work     |
|Wil   4/5/2010  Steady    Work     |
|Wil   4/5/2010  Steady    Work     |
|Wil   4/5/2010  Steady    Home     |
|Bill  7/14/2010 Stop      Home     |
|___________________________________|
```

i need to group/count it so that looks like this

```
Name   Date      Location    Status   Count
Tom    1/1/2010  Home        Ready    2
Bill   1/18/2010 Work        Go       1
Bill   7/14/2010 Home        Stop     1
Bob    2/19/2010 Field       Ready    2
etc.....
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the best way to do this is tricky based upon the format and properties of your data. But in general, you can use the `:group` argument of [ActiveRecord#find](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find).

```
Model.all(:select => 'COUNT(*) AS count, name, date, location, status', :group => 'name')
```

Or if using Rails 3

```
Model.all.select('COUNT(*) AS count, name, date, location, status').group('name')
```

If you always intend to group the data based on this relationship, consider adding it as a default scope to your model.

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope select('COUNT(*) AS count, name, date, location, status')
  default_scope group('name')
end
```